# Binomial exercise with different variances? Is it possible?

Tags: probability

Good evening,

[I honestly can't understand why in this excercise the variance is computed normally but then...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r76Od.png)

[In this one the variance is computed by dividing by n instead if multiplying by it as in the previous exercise?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBtpj.png)

Comment: Please make your post entirely self-contained.  Rather than linking to it, type out what the first exercise is and the proposed solution and similarly so for the second exercise.

Answer (score 0):

In the first exercise, your random variable is a count of things, represented by a binomial, $Y \sim B(n, p)$ and hence $Var(Y) = np(1-p)$.

In the second exercise, the random variable is a *proportion* of things, which is equal to the count (a binomial) divided by the number of trials, i.e. $\hat{P} = \frac{Y}{n}$. And since $n$ is a constant, we can write $Var(\hat{P}) = Var(\frac{Y}{n}) = \frac{1}{n^2}Var(Y) = \frac{1}{n^2}np(1-p) = \frac{p(1-p)}{n}$.